# print all validate parentheses, how does the recursive work here?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Implement an algorithm to print all valid (e.g., properly opened and closed) combinations of n-pairs of parentheses.
EXAMPLE:
input: 3 (e.g., 3 pairs of parentheses)
output: ()()(), ()(()), (())(), ((()))

the answer is :

```
private static void printPar(int count)
{
    char[] str = new char[count*2];
    printPar(count,count,str, 0);
}

private static void printPar(int l, int r, char[] str, int count)
{
    if(l < 0 || r < l)
        return;

    if (l ==0 && r == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    else
    {
        if (l > 0 )
        {
            str[count] = '(';
            printPar(l-1, r, str, count + 1);
        }

        if (r > 0)
        {
            str[count] = ')';
            printPar(l, r-1, str, count + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

But i dont quite fully understand the solution although someone claims the explanation is straightforward enough. (this code works fine)

In my opinion, this code works as when there is more left parentheses, then add the left parentheses. so, only condition of （（（））） coz the condition 
    if (l > 0 )
appear before r > 0 , so, it should always handle all the left ones first.

But how this code handle this situation "()(())"? i debug this code, and find out that after it prints out "((()))". it went to the situation of l =1, r =3, and str="((()))" and count = 2. which doesnt make sense to me.

Also, if someone can explain what is the time/space complexity, that would be much helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice that the two `if` statements are independent of one another; both of them can run on the same recursive call.

Comment: yea, i just notice that

Comment: it actually did for all the cases

Answer (score 8):

I drew a tree to show how the brackets are getting written for `count = 3`. Each node represents a function call, with its text being a `(` or `)`, depending on what the calling function added. The leaves are the calls where it gets printed.

[image]

Since the depth of this tree is (obviously) at most `2.count`, the space complexity is `O(count)`.

Since every function call can either add a `(` or a `)`, the time complexity is at most `O(2number of function calls)` = `O(22 count)`.

But, since the calls are conditional, the time complexity ends up being less, more specifically, it appears to be around `O(22 count/count)`, though I'm yet to prove that.

Comment: Side note: What utility did you use to draw this diagram?

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking for a good Linux diagram/tree/graph drawer and so far have only turned up TikZ

Answer (score 3):

The code runs successfully because it doesn't let r < l. If that is so, then it just discards the combination and returns. That means a right bracket can come only after a left bracket.

The order of complexity, if you count the discarded recursive calls as well is `(2n)!/( n! * n! )`. This is the number of permutations of n '(' and n ')'.

If you try to trace the code, it would run like follows:

```
(
 (
  (
   )
    )
     ) 
      ((()))
  )
   (
    )
     )
      (()())
   )
    (
     )
      (())()
 )
  (
   (
    )
     )
      ()(())
(
 )
  (
   )
    (
     )
      ()()()
```

Answer (score 3):

While recursing, the algorithm keeps track of the number of remaining left parentheses (l), the number of remaining right parenthesis (r), the result so far (str), and the number of parentheses generated (count).

If no parentheses remains, a result is printed.

If at least one left parenthesis remains, it is used, and the function recurses to generate all results starting with the current prefix

Then, if at least one right parenthesis remains, and at least one left parenthesis is not closed, a right parenthesis it used, and the function recurses.

> But how this code handle this situation "()(())"? i debug this code,
>   and find out that after it prints out "((()))". it went to the
>   situation of l =1, r =3, and str="((()))" and count = 2. which doesnt
>   make sense to me.

When after printing `((()))` the function is called with the parameters `1`, `3`, `((()))`, and `2`, `count=2` indicates that the only valid part of `str` is `((`. Then, it continues adding a `)` before recursing with the parameters `1`, `2`, `(()`, and `3`, resulting in `(()())` being the next combination printed, followed by `()(())`, and `()()()`.